# Find the first instance of multiple strings using regex

Tags: c++, regex

Suppose I have a string containing "ATGTTTGGATTAGGTAATGAAT".

I'd like to search the string for the first instance of either "TAG", "TAA", or "TGA".

To do this, I'd like to use regular expressions. I think `std::regex_search` will work, but I'm unsure how to write the syntax.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I need to retrieve the position of the first instance of "TAG", "TAA", or "TGA" (whichever comes first).

Comment: Why would you want to do this with a regular expression, when a simple 'find' would work. Or just 'strstr'?

Comment: find will find one substring, but not the first occurrence of a set of substrings

Comment: I think I just need to use something like "TAG|TAA|TGA".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main() {
    std::string s("ATGTTTGGATTAGGTAATGAAT");
    std::regex r("TAG|TAA|TGA");
    std::sregex_iterator first(s.begin(), s.end(), r);
    std::cout << "position: " << first->position() << std::endl; // position: 10
    return 0;
}
```

doc is here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str="ATGTTTGGATTAGGTAATGAAT";
    string regstr="TAG";
    const char *show;

    show=strstr(str.c_str(), regstr.c_str());//return the pointer of the first place reg 'TAG'，else return NULL。
    cout<<show<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the specific call in c++ (maybe that's what you are asking about), but this is your regex:

```
/T(A[GA]|GA)/
```

That is, find a "T" followed by either (an "A" and a ["G" or "A"]) or followed by "GA".

Comment: This is definitely a start. But yeah I need to figure out the specific call and a way to get the position.

Comment: Stick my regex into the example given on the [cplusplus.com reference for regex_search](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_search/) (NB: don't include the outer slashes).

Comment: That's actually what I'm working from but I'm not getting the results I want. I really just need the position (the index) of the first occurrence of one of the three strings. I'll keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

For this specific problem (that is, assuming that "TAG", "TAA", and "TGA" are the strings to be searched for, and not just representatives of a more general problem), a simple search is easier:

```
find 'T'
  if the next character is 'A' and the character after that is 'A' or 'G', matched;
  else if the next character is 'G' and the character after that is 'A' matched;
  else go back and try the next 'T'
```